# Adding Jena to Play Framework 2.0

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, jena

I want to add Apache jena as a dependency to my play framework 2.0 project.

I followed a tutorial I found [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies). I can't seem to find the correct resolver for a download

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    "jena.apache.org" % "jena" % "2.10.1" % "test"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
    resolvers += ***"apache-jena-2.10.1.zip" at "http://www.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/"***
  )
The "resolvers +=..." part seems to be what I have done wrong. Yet I can't find any solutions.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to add the repository at all. The artifacts are found in the [maven central repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jena/apache-jena-libs/2.10.1).

Just change your dependency to this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
  "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena-libs" % "2.10.1" % "test"
)
```

And remove the part where you tried to put in the repository so it looks like this:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  // Add your own project settings here      
)
```

If you want to use the Jena library in your main code (not only in unit tests) then strip the `test` part of the dependencies, like this:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  // Add your project dependencies here,
  "org.apache.jena" % "apache-jena-libs" % "2.10.1"
)
```